# How to order months in Python matplotlib?

Tags: python, sql, matplotlib

I have a table based on month names in SQL. sorted with the monthnumbers int. I want to make a line graph in Python Jupyter Notebook with matplotlib. BUT the line graph is giving me an alphabatical order ( a, b, c etc...)

This is not correct. I need the order in month numbers.

How can i do this?
i have both the monthnumber and the monthname in my select statement:

```
cursor = conx.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
Revenue = []
Monthnumber = [] 
Month = []
Maandnummer = []

for row in cursor:
    regio.append(str(row.Mond))
    Revenue.append(int(row.Revenue))
    Month.append(int(row.Month))
    Maandnummer.append(int(row.Monthnumber))

df = pd.read_sql(sql, conx)    
Months = ['januari','februari','maart','april', 'mei', 'juni', 'juli', 'augustus','september', 'oktober', 'november', 'december']
mapping = {Maandnummer: i for i, maandnummer in enumerate(Months)}
key = df['maandnummer'].map(mapping)

# Plot de inhoud van het dataframe (tabel als resultaat van query)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
aantal.sort()
plt.plot(key, omzet, 'ro')
plt.ylabel('Omzet')
plt.xlabel('Regio')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's hard to help you understand the solution you found when Googling, if you don't share it.

Comment: Months = ['januari','februari','maart','april', 'mei', 'juni', 'juli', 'augustus','september', 'oktober', 'november', 'december']
mapping = {maandnum: i for i, maandnum in enumerate(Months)}
key = df['maandnum'].map(mapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got lost between the different lists and columns, where some seem to include the same content. So here is a minimal example.

The idea is indeed to map the month to a number according to its position in the list. This can be done using a dictionary: `dict(zip(Months,range(len(Months))))`.
One may then apply this map to the dataframe column. In principle that is the approach from the code in the question, but while it is not reproducible, the following would be.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Months = ['januari','februari','maart','april', 'mei', 'juni', 'juli', 
          'augustus','september', 'oktober', 'november', 'december']

df = pd.DataFrame({"maand" : np.random.choice(Months, size=100),
                   "omzet" : np.random.binomial(100,0.5, size=100)})
mapping = dict(zip(Months,range(len(Months))))
df['maandnummer'] = df['maand'].map(mapping)


plt.figure()

plt.plot(df['maandnummer'], df["omzet"], 'ro')
plt.xticks(range(len(Months)),Months, rotation=45,ha="right")
plt.ylabel('Omzet')
plt.xlabel('Maand')
plt.show()
```

[image]