# Matplotlib-How do I plot a graph where the x values are the frequency of each y value?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

If I'm trying to plot a graph of the number of people born in each month, and I have a list like:

```
[ {"bob": "January"},{"Peter":"February"},{"Mary":"March"}, {"John":"March"}, {"Sully": "March"}, {"Kai":"April"} ,{"Jerry": "February"}, {"Polly":"may"}, {"Nina": "June"}, {"Mic": "July"}, {"Paul": "August"}, {"Ferry": "January"}]
```

What is the best way to plot a graph with the months on the x axis and the number of people who are born in that month on the y axis? I have the y values which are the months, but I'm having trouble with the x values. Do I have to go through the list and calculate the frequency of each month first? I will be working with a much bigger list with more than a thousand items and need a solution that is efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) to first flatten your list of dictionaries and then apply [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module to get the frequency of names for each month. Then you can extract the month names and the corresponding frequencies and plot them using a bar chart. Below is a sample answer using your provided data. If you want to sort the month names on the x-axis, you can use the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264409/how-to-order-months-in-python-matplotlib).

```
from collections import Counter, ChainMap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

dictionary = [{"bob": "January"},{"Peter":"February"},{"Mary":"March"}, {"John":"March"}, 
                  {"Sully": "March"}, {"Kai":"April"} ,{"Jerry": "February"}, {"Polly":"may"}, 
                  {"Nina": "June"}, {"Mic": "July"}, {"Paul": "August"}, {"Ferry": "January"}]

dict_flat = ChainMap(*dictionary)

frequency = Counter(dict_flat.values()).most_common()
x, y = zip(*frequency)

plt.bar(x, y, width=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]